# adding custom link into the step of google map's textual display of directions

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google map with directions service on transit mode and trying to add some link below the step displayed within textual display of directions.

When the step's mode is `WALKING` and it's duration is > 100 seconds, the link will be added at the bottom of it's `<td>` container.

I am trying to avoid handling the rendering of text based direction myself and would like to use `setPanel()` method of `DirectionsRenderer`.

For an Example, see the screenshot:

[image]

I tried to modify the step by looping through the response received via DirectionService, and the only thing I am able to do is modify the text.

I also thought of manipulating DOM but got confused on how to select it based on current structure.

Here is a link to JSFiddle if anyone want to play around it: http://jsfiddle.net/44j0dkv3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach:

The panel isn't populated yet when you iterate over the steps, so you can't access the related cells via the DOM. Store the desired link somewhere so that you have a relation between the link and the step-index.

After rendering the directions add the links to the desired cells:

```js
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));
var directionRequest = {
    origin: 'Chicago',
    destination: 'Los Angeles',
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT
};

directionsService.route(directionRequest, function (response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        var tmp = {}
        var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
        for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
            var steps = legs[i].steps;
            for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
                if (steps[j].travel_mode == 'WALKING' && steps[j].duration.value > 100) {
                    tmp[j] =document.createElement('a');
                    tmp[j].appendChild(document.createTextNode('text for a custom link'));
                    tmp[j].setAttribute('href','#something')
                    steps[j].instructions = '## - ' + steps[j].instructions;
                    // this is the step on which I want to add link
                    // the link will be at the bottom within this step's <td> container
                }
            }
        }

        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        
        //as it seems we need a short delay before the cells are accessible
        setTimeout(function () {
            var rows=document.querySelectorAll('#directions-panel table.adp-directions>tbody>tr[jsselect="steps"]');
            
            for(var k in tmp){
                rows.item(k).firstChild.appendChild(tmp[k]);
                rows.item(k).firstChild.style.background='tomato';
            }
        },10);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div id="directions-panel"></div>
```

Note: I haven't tested it much, it may be that you must modify the way to access the cells e.g. when waypoints will be used. There's also no guarantee that it will work in the future, because the markup for the panel isn't documented, so it must not be stable.